# Disable ENTER key event in extjs 3.4 combo

Tags: events, extjs, combobox, enter

I am using extjs 3.4. i need to disable ENTER key event for the combo. I tried with following code but could not succeed. Please help.

```
var combo = new Ext.form.comboBox({
  id: 'id',
  enableKeyEvents: true,
  store: store,
  triggerAction: 'all',
  listeners: {
   keydown: function(combo, e) {
     var key = e.getKey();
     if (key == e.ENTER) {
       e.stopEvent();
     }
   }
  }
});
```

The above does not work. Still enter event works for combo. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can simply use the following...

```
     onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){return false;}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at ext-all-debug.js you should be able to override the keyNav's enter handler after the combobox is created:

```
listeners: {
  render: function() {
    this.keyNav.enter = function() { ... };
  }
}
```